# Name of the following structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need the name of the algebraic structure that is like a vector space, but the vectors form a monoid, not a group; the field and the scalar multiplication stays the same.

Comment: Like this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semimodule

Comment: @Streeter so is it a semimodule over a field?

Comment: Yes, from what I can tell that's the best available descriptor. There is a notion of semivector space, but I believe that the "semi-" part there refers to the scenario where the underlying ring is a semifield.

I'm a little surprised that this doesn't have a specific name. Does the concept arise in something you are researching, or did you just wonder if such a structure had a specific name?

Comment: That is the structure I need, and I hoped there was a name for it.

Comment: I feel like even if you erase the "every vector has a negative" axiom from the definition of vector space, you can still get it back by acting with $-1$ from the field, and so every commutative monoid acted on by a field will actually turn out to be an abelian group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest thing to what you are talking about is a [semimodule over a semifield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semifield) which is a *commutative* monoid acted upon by a semifield. For both the semimodule and the semiring, we've dropped the condition that what used to be an abelian group now does not necessarily have inverses for its elements.

The situation is like Joppy mentioned in the comments: if you $V$ which is a vector space except that it does not have additive inverses, and you have a field acting on it in the normal way, then in fact $-1\cdot v$ is defined for every $v\in V$, and that is the additive inverse of $v$. So to have something truly different you need to drop the requirement of additive inverses from "the field" as well.

Actually everything above can still be said if we're talking about just a semimodule over a semi*ring* (with identity.)

Comment: Upon some analysis, you are right, the "field" need not have aditive inverses. Thanks.